# Templated HTML creating web page, but inserting space between each letter (number, etc) outputted

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am working on a version of the templated HTML as explained at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates. My code gets me all the way to a correctly formatted web page, but for one small problem: The code is sticking a white space in between each item. So, I get "a n i t e m" in instead of "an item". (Screen shot of actual output is below.)

I suspect that the culprit is in the html file which is also reprinted below.

[image: Screenshot]

I have researched templated html and "white spaces", 'inserted spaces", etc., and can find nobody else that has had this issue.

Minimal Complete Verifiable Example:

## Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<table>
    <ul type="square">
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
          <li><? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <?= data[i][j] ?>
          <? } ?></li><br>
      <? } ?>
    </ul>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `data` comes from

## Code.gs

```
function doGet(){
    var instrument = "Martin D-18 (↓1/2)"; 
    var tuning = "Drop D";
    var key ="Db";
    var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
    t.data = [instrument, tuning, key];
    return t.evaluate();
}
```

In real world, The variables instrument, tuning, key are simple strings retrieved from my spreadsheet, but I was able to reproduce the same issue, if I replace them with variables of string type as shown above.

## Update -

re monofont not issue. Here's the log from the script showing the underlying variables that the html is parsing. As you can see, no inappropriate spaces.

```
[19-04-26 13:27:24:743 EDT] instrument = Martin D-18 (↓1/2)
[19-04-26 13:27:24:743 EDT] tuning = Drop D
[19-04-26 13:27:24:744 EDT] settings = 
[19-04-26 13:27:24:744 EDT] key = Db
[19-04-26 13:27:24:745 EDT] chord = D
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the style sheet to make sure that isn't some sort of character spacing?

Comment: I think the issue is due to the blank spaces you are leaving between the open and close scriptlets... I don't really know google-apps-script, but that seems to be an issue...

Comment: If this was PHP code, than this would certainly be the problem. There can be any blank spaces between <?php and ;?> and they won't show up in the HTML, but if there is blank space in HTML it may show up. I used "may" and not "will" because HTML will not render consecutive spaces, for example.

Comment: The problem existed before I added the CSS. And yes, definitely spaces. If you copy the page and paste into a word processor, there are in fact spaces between each.

Comment: Really, I wouldn't care except that the first item in the list I want to render as a link and it won't of course with the spaces.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster re that tip.  Am always at loggerheads on how much to provide as I seem to get dissed for too little sometimes.

Comment: See [mcve].  The first step: Did you `Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem`?  You'll easily find the problem if you follow the methods provided there one by one. Debugging is art. And you won't get it by searching Oh I see space.. Let me search for "white spaces", 'inserted spaces"....  Put in time.  In the long run, You'll eventually be saving time and not wasting it.

Comment: Thank you. Will take that to heart @TheMaster

Comment: @TheMaster: Thanks for edits to the way I asked this question. Helps me to understand what "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" is in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

`data` is a 1 dimensional array. You're iterating over it twice in a nested fashion.

If `data[i]`(for i =0) is the string,

```
data[0] "Martin D-18 (↓1/2)"
```

`data[i][j]` will be strings:

```
data[0][0] M
data[0][1] a
data[0][2] r
data[0][3] t
data[0][4] i
data[0][5] n
data[0][6]
data[0][7] D
data[0][8] -
data[0][9] 1
data[0][10] 8
data[0][11]
data[0][12] (
data[0][13] ↓
data[0][14] 1
data[0][15] /
data[0][16] 2
data[0][17] )
```

as Strings are iterable just like Arrays.

#### Solution:

Loop once per element in `data` array.

#### Snippet:

```
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  <li><?= data[i] ?></li><br>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to be effusive and thankful on this site, But, wow. Thanks to @TheMaster and ndvo for your expertise and time. Because now I understand a whole bunch more what is going on, and my mission critical problem is fixed!

Answer (score 1):

It is important to avoid adding extra spaces in the HTML.

Inside <? and ?> you may add as many spaces as you want, but spaces outside of it are spaces in HTML and will be rendered by the browser.

This code removes such extra spaces.

```
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      <li><? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { 
        ?><?= data[i][j] ?><?
       } ?></li><br>

  <? } ?>
```

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55872977/935645) is better. The problem was not only the spaces in HTML, it was the iteration over the string.

Comment: Tried it. No love. Still spaces.

Comment: Truthfully, this would be clearer to me if I knew what was happening in this script. Is "i" letters (or single discreet elements whether letters, numbers, punctuation) and "j" discrete words or what?

Comment: Let me try to break it down. "var i =0" creates a variable called "i" and stores 0 in it, that is "i" equals 0. When you call "data[i]" you are saying asking for the ith position in data. Data must be something like ['a','b','c'] and 'a' is in the zeroth position, therefore, data[0] is 'a'. The "for" is used to run this code multiple times. The first time i will be 0, the second time i will be 1 and so on, until is is no longer less then data.length "i<data.length". You have one for inside another for, therefore the code will run the first time with i=0 and j=0, the second time with i=0, j=1

Comment: When j is no longer less then data[0].length "j<data[i].length" the code will continue to i=1 j=0.